# Normality Condition for a 2 sample difference in population means

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I was recently working on a statistics problem from AP Statistics FRQ 2018:[Here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJcMl.png)

I don't understand how we got the normality condition which is required for the 2 sample difference in population means test. Specifically,  the central limit theorem states for a large sample size, greater than 30, the distribution of *sample means* will be normally distributed. However, we only took 1 sample and how do we even know the distribution of this sample is normally distributed?

Much thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Sample sizes are 110 and 100 respectively, not 1,

Comment: but doesn't central limit theorem apply to taking repeated samples and taking the means? However, here , we only took one sample and took the mean. So, I think CLT doesn't apply here?

Comment: The number 30 is often mistaken for some sort of guaranteed number for the CLT to converge to normality. // For some distributions (e.g,. uniform) 10 is enough, for others (e.g., exponential, Pareto) 100 is not quite enough or totally inadequate. **Best just to forget about 30 as a CLT guarantee.** // In many elementary examples (e.g., your link) one is simply told that data are normal (with no explanation why that is known to be true). // Sometimes, normality tests or normal probability plots (Q-Q plots) can be helpful in assessing normality of the population from which a sample was drawn.

Comment: I think you misunderstand 'sample'. The procedures had  repeated samples of 110 and 100 respectively, so CLT applies to each procedure.   You are comparing 2 populations each with sample means and variances, and trying to determine if the means are statistically different.

Comment: Elementary texts and software dialog boxes sometimes confuse 'sample' (set of observations) with `observation' (individual data point.

Answer (score 1):

Minitab will accept summarized data. Here is the output for a Welch one-sided t test. This test assumes data are normal, but not that variances are equal. You can use formulas
from a textbook to verify these computations.
I will leave the interpretation of the
results up to you.

```
Two-Sample T-Test and CI 

Sample    N   Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       110  217.0   34.0      3.2
2       100  186.0   29.0      2.9


Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  31.00
95% lower bound for difference:  23.81
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs >): 
  T-Value = 7.13  P-Value = 0.000  DF = 207
```

Because the two sample standard deviations are about the same a pooled test (easier to compute) will give similar results. But because sample sizes differ, the pooled T statistic will not be exactly the same.

Here is Minitab output for the pooled test:

```
Two-Sample T-Test and CI 

Sample    N   Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       110  217.0   34.0      3.2
2       100  186.0   29.0      2.9

Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  31.00
95% lower bound for difference:  23.76
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs >): 
  T-Value = 7.07  P-Value = 0.000  DF = 208
Both use Pooled StDev = 31.7186
```

Note: 'Both' above means the T test and the CI both use the pooled standard deviation shown.